# How to add data to FormData and submit?

Tags: javascript, php, ecmascript-6

After passing the quiz, the user fills in the form with the fields: Name and Phone and sends the data to the mail. I have written code to submit a form. Now I need to make it so that when the form is submitted, the user's selected responses are also sent. The user's selected responses are stored in a userData object and

```js
//selected user responses
const userData = {
  gender: "...",
  date: "...",
  month: "...",
  year: "...",
  allergy: "...",
};

//submit form
const form = document.getElementById("order_form");
form.addEventListener("submit", formSend);

async function formSend(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  let error = formValidate(form);
  let formData = new FormData(form);

  if (error === 0) {
    let response = await fetch("sendmail.php", {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData,
    });
    if (response.ok) {
      let result = await response.json();
      form.reset();
    }
  }
}

//sendmail.php 

//body
if (trim(!empty($_POST['name']))) {
    $body .= '<p><strong>Имя:</strong>' . $_POST['name'] . '</p>';
}
if (trim(!empty($_POST['phone']))) {
    $body .= '<p><strong>Телефон:</strong>' . $_POST['phone'] . '</p>';
}
```

Comment: [`FormData.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `append` method of `FormData`

```
formData.append('gender', userData.gender);
formData.append('date', userData.date);
```

Comment: Let me know if it is solved your issue

Comment: userData is dynamically generated depending on the responses. How can I add them to the submitted form?

Comment: Do you want to add some values to the form that is already submitted? I mean when userData is getting created? Before or After submission?

Comment: No, the form is sent along with the data, at the last stage of the quiz. It's just that userData is generated dynamically depending on the user's responses. I don't statically specify ('gender', 'Male') etc.

Comment: You mean both keys and values in userData is getting generated from user response or values only?

Comment: Depending on the user's choice, only values ​​are generated. Keys remain static

Comment: Please check updated answer. Is it what you need?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do I need to add fields to the body in sendmail.php as I indicated in the example for the fields from the form?